# Importing a trained pipeline model from pyspark to scala?

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Is it possible to load a trained pipeline model from a pyspark environment to scala ?
I am trying to do it but I am having this error

```
requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel but found class name pyspark.ml.pipeline.PipelineModel
```

To be more precise, I have a pyspark pipeline model :

```
pipe = Pipeline(stages=[transformer_1, transformer_2, RandomForestClassifier])
pipe_model = pipe.fit(data)
pipe_model.save("model.model")
```

When trying to load this model in scala

```
saved_pipeline_model = PipelineModel.load("model.model")
```

I had the error above, when I looked in the org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel I found that the error is coming from the load function

```
    def load(
    expectedClassName: String,
    sc: SparkContext,
    path: String): (String, Array[PipelineStage]) = instrumented { instr =>
  val metadata = DefaultParamsReader.loadMetadata(path, sc, expectedClassName)



/**
   * Load metadata saved using [[DefaultParamsWriter.saveMetadata()]]
   *
   * @param expectedClassName  If non empty, this is checked against the loaded metadata.
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if expectedClassName is specified and does not match metadata
   */
  def loadMetadata(path: String, sc: SparkContext, expectedClassName: String = ""): Metadata = {
    val metadataPath = new Path(path, "metadata").toString
    val metadataStr = sc.textFile(metadataPath, 1).first()
    parseMetadata(metadataStr, expectedClassName)
  }
```

Indeed, the loadMetada checks if expectedClassName is the same as in the metadata folder.

Comment: I don't know much about spark mllib: how is stored your model, and how is it loaded?

Comment: I edit the question to explain more my problem

Comment: Sorry but I can't find a better way than writing your own metadata reader  :\ or maybe an alternative python writer

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with editing the metadata myself :

```
{"class":"pyspark.ml.pipeline.PipelineModel","timestamp":1635178267710,..}
```

to

```
{"class":,"timestamp":1635178267710,..}
```